# Upgraded rails and rspec now test is not passing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I can't quite figure out why these tests aren't passing all of a sudden:

```
Failure/Error: @user = test_sign_in(Factory(:user))
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `test_sign_in' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_3::Nested_1::Nested_2:0x00000100a908e8>
```

There are a bunch that fail on test_sign_in and then another test that fails:

```
     1) SessionsController POST 'create' with valid email and password should sign the user in
     Failure/Error: controller.should be_signed_in
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate?' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:51:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) SessionsController DELETE 'destroy' should sign a user out
     Failure/Error: controller.should_not be_signed_in
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate?' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:66:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) UsersController POST 'create' success should sign the user in
     Failure/Error: controller.should be_signed_in
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate?' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:171:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) Users sign in/out success should sign a user in and out
     Failure/Error: controller.should be_signed_in
       expected signed_in? to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/users_spec.rb:68:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: When you upgraded rspec, did you overwrite your spec/spec_helper.rb file? Was test_sign_in defined there?

Comment: Yes, and I fixed that part. I added all the failures I am seeing into the original question.

Comment: Is `test_sign_in` defined somewhere? What object is nil on `./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:51`?